# how to remove subview from class method in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I have an app.In this app so many class methods used.I want to know is it possible to remove subview from class mehtod?

```
 +(void)addPregressIndicator:(NSString *)strText view:(UIView *)ShowView
{
    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *busyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame];
    busyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    busyView.opaque          = YES;

    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 95, 95)];

    container.layer.borderWidth     = 5;
    container.layer.cornerRadius    = 10;
    container.layer.borderColor     = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *av = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    av.center                   = CGPointMake(container.center.x, 34);
    av.hidesWhenStopped         = NO;
    [av startAnimating];

    UILabel *lbl                = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 95, 30)];
    lbl.text                    = strText;
    lbl.textAlignment           = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.center                  = CGPointMake(container.center.x, 70);
    lbl.textColor               = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.backgroundColor         = [UIColor clearColor];

    [container addSubview:av];
    [container addSubview:lbl];

    container.center = busyView.center;

    [busyView addSubview:container];

    [ShowView addSubview:busyView];



}

+(void)removePregressIndicator:(UIView *)hideView;

{
    // i want remove busyview that subview in viewcontroller.
}
```

Please help me to remove subivew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a unique tag for the busyView like this `busyView.tag = your unique tag;`

And then you can remove the view with this code

```
+(void)removePregressIndicator:(UIView *)hideView;
{
    UIView *busyView = [hideView viewWithTag:your unique tag];
    if (busyView){
        [busyView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

You should make sure that the busyView tag is unique for all the subviews of `hideView`.

Comment: Can i remove without tag

Comment: In alternative you can create a basic UIView subclass, initialize busyView as an instance of this subclass and when you want to remove it iterate through the hideView subviews and remove the view that is an instance of your subclass

Comment: Or you could use an instance variable to hold a reference to the view?

Comment: Well, actually you can't access an instance variable inside a class method

Comment: nice answer thanx.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (void)removePregressIndicator:(UIView *)hideView;
{
    UIView *progView=[self.view viewWithTag:YourTag];
    [progView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: hidview means which added progress indicator.you mean to say i will remove self.view?

Comment: i want to remove busyview that added on self.view

Comment: set tag to busyView, when you remove it just find view with it's tag,

Answer (score 0):

Assigne tag to a each view and access the view with tag and put it

```
+(void)removePregressIndicator:(UIView *)hideView;

{
      UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:assigne_tag];
     [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Yeah there is already answer that gives the same advice.  Why add another one?

Comment: becz i have an problem with textview.i give tag 1 in textview & same tag given in view